# REST: how to tell server to do some background process

Tags: rest

I am building a client-side product with REST. All user interaction will be done with a browser (the config stuff will be on a server running on localhost). I want everything to be REST compliant, even though the application will be running on a client's machine on `localhost` and will never be accessible from the outside.

The commands are pretty simple:

- update
- restart
- sync

Here's what I've come up with:

- POST to / with 'action' parameter (JSON) detailing specifics
- PUT a new resource

  - subsequent GET requests will return the status
  - when the command is complete, the resource is deleted

**What would be the most RESTful way to implement this?**

Note:

I'm not asking for scrutinization of my software architecture. I have reasons for choosing a REST interface instead of a unix domain socket, CLI interface, or even a regular GUI interface. The justification would overcomplicate the question and make it too localized.

I have had the same need on a couple of different projects (both client only and server) and I am looking for community input on best practices.

Comment: What do you mean by "client only application". Do you mean a single-page [RIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_application)?

Comment: What I mean is the application would be running on a client's machine on localhost only. Only the user would be able to access it. This will never be set up on an open port. Editing question to reflect that.

Comment: This should be a desktop app then

Comment: It is. It's a server running in the background that the user interacts with via a web browser, and optionally via a RESTful interface.

Comment: REST is a great way of thinking about information architecture, but it's a hammer and not every problem is a nail.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos- I understand that, but that's not exactly the question here. I am marketing this to administrators to implement on the computers they manage, as well as to end users. For admins, this information needs to be scriptable, for end users, this information needs to be easy. The client server will be connecting to a remote server, which WILL be REST compliant. The integration of the two will need to be seamless (same structure). The client will need commands to be run periodically, the remote server will not. Besides the commands, REST is a good solution to this particular problem.

Comment: What does the "update" command do? Does "restart" restart the application or restart some process? Is "sync" also a background process?

Comment: @jhericks- In this case, the "restart" command restarts the application, but most of the commands will start background processes. The application will not immediately exit, but will stop accepting new connections until everything that is currently being processed is finished processing. It's a little complicated, but it mostly fits the REST model, except for commands.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would POST to a /process resource with the appropriate parameters necessary to start the process, then I would have it return a Location header to that resource that actually represents the process status (/process/123). You can then use GET on that process to get the latest information about it.

I would not automatically delete the process, because if you do that, the client will not know if the process finished properly or not, just simply that it finished (well, stopped running).

Noting that, the client can certainly DELETE the resource when it is done, or you can clean it up later after some reasonable time where whoever was interested in it is likely not to be any more.

Comment: This sounds quite reasonable. I'll wait for a bit before I accept, but this is definitely helpful.